# Python version of Moment.js fromNow()

Tags: python, momentjs

I am a big fan of the Moment.js function which returns a human-readable version of how long ago something happens:

```
console.log( moment([2018, 0, 29]).fromNow() )
# outputs: 4 years ago
```

I've been looking everywhere and I cannot fund a Python equivalent. Am I just a bad googler or does it exist?

Comment: Comment to clarify: I'M looking for the Python equivalent of the Moment.js function, not just a way to convert to years:

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

from_now = datetime.now() - datetime(2018, 1, 29)

print(str(from_now))
print(f'{from_now.days / 365:.1f} years ago')
```

prints

```
1673 days, 0:49:44.022284
4.6 years ago
```

Comment: I'm looking for more than just years: the Moment fromNow() functionality returns all possible date types, like years, months, days, hours, seconds etc.

Comment: Obviously you can convert from the seconds (which can be retrieved from the time delta object) to any desired time quantity.

Comment: So there's not an existing library or function on the datetime or timedelta  classes that already do this? I find the moment.js function so useful its hard to beleive it doesn't already exist.